# Does Salesforce1 support translation for recordtypes?

Tags: salesforce1-app

Does Salesforce1 support translation for recordtypes ?As we have some recordtypes for Accounts translated 
via translated workbench but these translated  value are not available in Salesforce1.

Answer (score 0):

It still does not ...yet to be developed for SF1 ..

Comment: Can you add some sort of support for this claim?

Comment: We raised an issue with salesforce   so the internal team confirmed it

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to include that detail and quote as much of the conversation as makes sense here. This answer as is doesn't really help the community much.